# CoreData addObserver NSKeyValueChangeInsertion

Tags: core-data, ios, observer-pattern

Is there a way to get the object that has been added using `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` with option `NSKeyValueChangeInsertion` on an `NSManagedObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. From the documentation for `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`:

> `change` A dictionary that describes the changes that have been made to the value of the property at the key path keyPath relative to object. Entries are described in “Keys used by the change dictionary.”

And further down:

> `NSKeyValueChangeKindKey`
>   An NSNumber object that contains a value corresponding to one of the NSKeyValueChangeKindKey enumerations, indicating what sort of change has occurred.
>
> `NSKeyValueChangeIndexesKey` 
>   If the value of the NSKeyValueChangeKindKey entry is NSKeyValueChangeInsertion, NSKeyValueChangeRemoval, or NSKeyValueChangeReplacement, the value of this key is an NSIndexSet object that contains the indexes of the inserted, removed, or replaced objects.

Comment: Thank you very much, I somehow missed it.